# Liferay Plugins SDK throws NoClassDefFoundError for BooleanFilter Class

Tags: eclipse-plugin, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui, liferay-ide

I got this error when I registered a BaseIndexer Class on liferay-portlet.xml file. I'm using Liferay-7 and developing a portlet using the liferay-plugins SDK.I get this error only when I register BaseIndexer class in the liferay-portlet.xml. I kindly request anyone to diagonise the error and feel free to ask any more info regarding my platform.

*Steps Undertaken:
I tried to add many versions of com.liferay.kernal jar files into the project.*

> 14:59:15,488 INFO  [pool-116-thread-2][PortletHotDeployListener:201]
>   Registering portlets for MyCT-portlet 14:59:15,504 ERROR
>   [pool-116-thread-2][HotDeployImpl:240]
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error
>   registering portlets for MyCT-portlet
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployException: Error
>   registering portlets for MyCT-portlet     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.BaseHotDeployListener.throwHotDeployException(BaseHotDeployListener.java:38)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:97)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:237)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:104)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:28)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:164)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:154)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:75)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:58)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:54)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:116)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ServletContextListenerExceptionAdapter.contextInitialized(ServletContextListenerExceptionAdapter.java:51)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor462.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.ListenerRegistration$EventListenerInvocationHandler.invoke(ListenerRegistration.java:145)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy503.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.ContextController.doAddListenerRegistration(ContextController.java:357)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.ContextController.addListenerRegistration(ContextController.java:310)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.customizer.ContextListenerTrackerCustomizer.addingService(ContextListenerTrackerCustomizer.java:67)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.customizer.ContextListenerTrackerCustomizer.addingService(ContextListenerTrackerCustomizer.java:1)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:941)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:901)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:917)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:862)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:801)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:225)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:464)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:482)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:1001)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabBundleProcessor.initListeners(WabBundleProcessor.java:569)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabBundleProcessor.init(WabBundleProcessor.java:201)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer._initWabBundle(WebBundleDeployer.java:186)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer.doStart(WebBundleDeployer.java:106)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabFactory$WABExtension.start(WabFactory.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:482)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:1)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)
>     at
>   org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:444)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:905)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:165)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:75)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:67)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:102)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:461)
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:452)     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:402)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:421)
>     at aQute.remote.agent.AgentServer.start(AgentServer.java:163)   at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1147.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   aQute.remote.util.Link.executeCommand(Link.java:335)  at
>   aQute.remote.util.Link$2.run(Link.java:173)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.filter.BooleanFilter cannot be found**
>   by MyCT-portlet_7.0.0.1   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy878.(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ProxyUtil.newProxyInstance(ProxyUtil.java:114)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ProxyFactory.newInstance(ProxyFactory.java:57)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.newInstance(PortletBagFactory.java:494)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.newInstance(PortletBagFactory.java:486)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.newIndexers(PortletBagFactory.java:474)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.create(PortletBagFactory.java:121)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.service.impl.PortletLocalServiceImpl.initWAR(PortletLocalServiceImpl.java:869)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor809.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:163)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:169)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.initWAR(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.PortletLocalServiceUtil.initWAR(PortletLocalServiceUtil.java:332)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:209)
>     at
>   com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:94)
>     ... 67 more

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.filter` as an import package to you bundles MANIFEST.MF. If you have more then one bundle in the classpath exporting this package then add a version to the import definition to avoid conflicts.